# cant concatenate my original excel with the result of my code due to an error

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to concatenate the result of this code into the same header of "Extraction_DI.xlsx" starting column 19 but i keep getting errors.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


kpi_workbook=pd.read_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Extraction_DI.xlsx')
kpi_workbook['Date création DI'] = pd.to_datetime(kpi_workbook['Date création DI'])
kpi_workbook['Anné'] = kpi_workbook['Date création DI'].dt.year
kpi_workbook['Moi'] = kpi_workbook['Date création DI'].dt.month
kpi_workbook['Jour'] = kpi_workbook['Date création DI'].dt.day
selected_columns = ['Date création DI', 'Anné', 'Moi', 'Jour']

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Extraction_DI.xlsx')
writer.book = pd.load_workbook(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Extraction_DI.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

kpi_workbook[selected_columns].to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=19)

writer.save()
```

I avoid using openpyxl instead I try to stick to pandas, because some of my excels have over 200K lines, the folowing is the error I get :

```
  File "d:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Done_Performance_Date filter - Copy.py", line 5, in <module>
    kpi_workbook=pd.read_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Extraction_DI.xlsx')
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\seljoukia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 478, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, storage_options=storage_options, engine=engine)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\seljoukia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pandas\io\excel\_base.py", line 1500, in __init__ 
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.
```

Comment: Are you sure you have an excel file and not a CSV? What is the output of `print(open('Extraction_DI.xlsx', 'rb').read(2) == b'PK')`?

Comment: it the same excel i use to test a lot of programs, they all work except this one

Comment: what does 'br', (2) and b'PK' stand for ?

Comment: `rb`: Read Binary and `PK` is the two first bytes of excel file (compressed zip). I wanted to be sure the file is a real excel file. Try to force the engine manually `pd.read_exce(..., engine='openpyxl')`. Don't forget to install it if it's not already the case. `pip install openpyxl`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out [ask] for tips like how to write a good title -- maybe something like "Why do I need to 'specify an engine manually' when reading an Excel file?" You should also reduce the amount of code here since the error occurs early on; see [mre].

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it on my own i used the following code :
the code would poduce an excel with an output

```
kpi_workbook[selected_columns].to_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Performance_date filter.xlsx')
```

i then sat a variable to locate the output produced by the program

```
date_filter = pd.read_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Performance_date filter.xlsx')
```

dropped the annex column:

```
date_filter = date_filter.drop('Unnamed: 0',axis=1 )
```

concatenated the 2 excels:

```
concatenated = pd.concat([kpi_workbook1, date_filter], axis=1)
```

and made it create a new excel with all the data merged into one:

```
concatenated.to_excel(r'D:\Maintenance\Bloc 6\PROJECT KPI\Performance\Source code\Extraction_DI_2.xlsx')
```